# Internet Explorer does not show links styled as they are in Visual Studio designer

Tags: css, visual-studio, internet-explorer, designer

I use a master page and a theme. After finding that the style does not correctly work in the browser, I took the rendered html and created an html page in visual studio in order to see everything in the designer. I foun the style is showing correctly in visual studio disigner. When I tried to see the page in IE, the styl again didn't work.

Here is the style:

```
#menu div.menu a
{
    display: block;
    color: #FFFF00;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

and here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Welcome.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMjA5MTQxNjgzNWRkziD2ncxUdFPJZHawenZNb39FJFc=" />
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Site name</h1>
    </div> 
    <div id="mainnav"></div> 
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu">

            <a id="ctl00_cphRight1_LoginView1_hlLogin" href="Login.aspx">Login</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That rule should be for

```
#menu div.menu a
```

You're missing the leading #